# Value does not fall within the expected range, while Registering Line in TAPI3.Lib

Tags: c#-4.0, tapi

I am getting a problem while registering a line using `TAPI3.Lib`
This is where I get the exception:

```
registertoken[line] = 
      tobj.RegisterCallNotifications(
               ia[line], true, true,
               TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO | TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_DATAMODEM,
               1);
```

`tobj` is object of type `TAPI3Lib.TAPIClass`

When the compiler executes the above code then it throws the exception

**Value does not fall within the expected range**

Currently i am using Windows 7.

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory.

Comment: Sir, actually i am new to TAPI3 and So i am not getting it why it is giving this exception while regestring?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I don't see how this is self-explanatory.